# Ruby relation between same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model in rails, lets say `User`, which i want to have a relation to another user.

User A, can be the boss of User B and User B can be the boss of User C and D.

This relation is a one-to-many. One user can stand above multiple users.

How would i do this.
My user model has currently an `ID` with the name `boss_id`, which will be nil if the user is in the top of the food chain.

My active record class looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users #People beneath the user
  belongs_to :user
end
```

But now I want to use relation with a name. Lets say `boss` and `followers`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how it would look like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :boss, :class_name => 'User'
    has_many :followers, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :boss_id

end
```

Answer (score 1):

It is called self join

## Self Joins

In designing a data model, you will sometimes find a model that should have a relation to itself. For example, you may want to store all employees in a single database model, but be able to trace relationships such as between manager and subordinates. This situation can be modeled with self-joining associations:

Employee example:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :subordinates, :class_name => "Employee"
  belongs_to :manager, :class_name => "Employee", :foreign_key => "manager_id"

end
```

With this setup, you can retrieve **@employee.subordinates** and **@employee.manager**.